# Hybris DefaultB2BCheckoutFacade.placeOrder taking too long to finish

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I'd like to ask about possible causes/solutions for our current issue. We have a simple checkout page. Inside, we have 5 products only. After clicking the place order button, we call our controller. Inside this controller, we only do simple validations like user, terms, and authorized payment. We also load the cart here. By the end, we call the placeOrder of DefaultB2BCheckoutFacade. We didn't create our custom class so this is out of the box from the b2b-accelerator. With 5 products, we are seeing 18 seconds to fully process the request. Can you please help us understand the issue?

**EDIT:** I overrode the placeOrder method of DefaultB2BCheckoutFacade with the exact logic. Below are the times it took to finish each call.

Validation took: 5.6497767 seconds -> `if (isValidCheckoutCart(placeOrderData))`

Place order took: 6.5388391 seconds -> `return (T) super.placeOrder();`

Total time took: 12.1888468 seconds -> placeOrder method

Comment: what is your DB? You can use APM tools to find whole details.

Comment: For our local, we use HSQLDB while SQL Server in our environments. Even in our local, we encounter this issue. We have Dynatrace but I don't think it is properly set up yet because I can't see our application there.

Comment: The HSQLDB is very slow. I prefer MYSQL/MariaDB for local development.

Answer (score 0):

If your project has a large number of products/categories/price rows, try to use a different cache region for those types.

This configuration has worked for me in the past:

```
regioncache.productregion.size=100000
regioncache.productregion.evictionpolicy=LRU
regioncache.productregion.exclusiveComputation=false
regioncache.productregion.statsEnabled=true
regioncache.categoryregion.size=100000
regioncache.categoryregion.evictionpolicy=LRU
regioncache.categoryregion.exclusiveComputation=false
regioncache.categoryregion.statsEnabled=true
regioncache.pricerowregion.size=100000
regioncache.pricerowregion.evictionpolicy=LRU
regioncache.pricerowregion.exclusiveComputation=false
regioncache.pricerowregion.statsEnabled=true
```